# push and pop operation using stack on string

Tags: c, pointers, push

Please answer
A string x is well-matched if (i) it has an equal number of '(' and ')' letters, and (ii) for each ')' in x, there is a unique '(' that before it in x. For example, the strings "a()", "(a)" and "(a(a))" are well-matched whereas "a(", ")a(" and "())(" are NOT well-matched. The following function is supposed to return 1 if the given string x is well-matched, and is supposed to return 0 otherwise:

```
int matched(char *x) {
  int i;
  stack_t s;
  init(&s);
  for(i = 0; x[i] != '\0'; i++) {
    switch(x[i]) {
    case '(':
      push(&s, x[i]); break;
    case ')':
      if(isEmpty(&s)) return 0;
      if(pop(&s) == '(') return 1;
      else return 0;
    }
  }
  return isEmpty(&s);
}
```

Assuming that push() operations never fail, the above function:

Note: The isEmpty() function correctly returns 1 if the stack is empty, and returns 0 otherwise.
 A. works correctly on all strings
 B. returns the wrong answer on the input "a()"
 C. returns the wrong answer on the input ")a"
 D. returns the wrong answer on the input "())"

Comment: Can anybody explain it and give me the correct reason for choosing any of the below:

Comment: A. works correctly on all strings B. returns the wrong answer on the input "a()" C. returns the wrong answer on the input ")a" D. returns the wrong answer on the input "())"

Comment: You also don't need a stack; a counter will be enough, because you never push anything other than open parentheses. Your cloing-parentheses clause is wrong, too: You should ony return false if the stack is empty, otherwise pop and proceed; don't return.

Comment: @MOehm It's likely an assignment/homework meant to demonstrate the use of the stack.

Comment: @szczurcio: Yeah, probably, but then the task should really make use of the stack's contents.such as checking strings with different kinds of brackets.

Comment: So...looking at your posted code, do you see *any* way one can see a character *after* any `)` with your current algorithm? You could push a hundred `(`, and as soon as you encounter a single `)` *all* code paths in that case `return` something, leaving no chance to process the hopefully-remaining 99 other `)`

Comment: `if(pop(&s) == '(') return 1;
      else return 0;` shoud be `if(pop(&s) != '(') return 0;`

Answer (score 1):

You've got the basic idea right: Walk through the string and push opening parens, pop closing parens. You have two basic cases of mismatched parentheses: (1) You close a parenthesis that wasn't opened. In that case, you underflow the stack. (2) You don't close a parenthesis that was opened. Here, you still have opening parens on the stack after you have walked the string.

Your error is when you pop the stack: Wen the stack is empty, you would underflow it, and so you (correctly) return false. When you have successfully popped a parenthesis, don't return. You must check the rest of the string for correctness. `return` leaves the function and also breaks the loop. It does not set a return value for later, it returns immediately.

So:

```
int matched(const char *x)
{
    int i, j;
    stack_t s;

    init(&s);

    for (i = 0; x[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        switch (x[i]) {
        case '(':
            push(&s, i);
            printf("Opening paren at %d\n", i);
            break;

        case ')':
            if (isEmpty(&s)) return 0;
            j = pop(&s);
            printf("Closing paren opened at %d at %d\n", j, i);
            break;
        }
    }

    return isEmpty(&s);
}
```

I've taken the liberty to push the parnetheses' positions, so that there is at least some meaningful data on the stack. The `printf` statements are just for illustration.

(Such small problems can usually be played through withz pencil and paper or by printing information during development.)

Comment: the stack is a bit superfluous; you could get away with a `int parencnt;`

Comment: @sp2danny: I know and I've said so in a comment on the question. Another commenter suggested that this is an exercide to use the stack. (If so, the excercise is poor.)